# From DLL to java classes

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface, native-code

I have dll file which is controlling a device, I need a tool to generate java classes which take the dll file as an input and generate all the need JNI classes.

Note: I don't have the C,C++ code for that DLL.

Comment: *"I need a tool"*  We need a question.  What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are doing all this so that you can call C++ methods through Java.
Instead use JNA library. It does not require any explicit JNI classes to be built. You can directly call C++methods. Read more about it [here](https://jna.java.net/)